# GThreadPool is not creating more than N threads

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, glib

I'm trying to understand why I cannot start more than 4 threads when using a GThreadPool.

```
pool = g_thread_pool_new ((GFunc)func, (gpointer)&values, g_get_num_processors (), TRUE, NULL);
g_thread_pool_push (pool, val, NULL);
g_thread_pool_push (pool, val, NULL);
g_thread_pool_push (pool, val, NULL);
g_thread_pool_push (pool, val, NULL);
g_thread_pool_push (pool, val, NULL);
```

The function `g_get_num_processors ()` give me `4` as result and I'm using it because I want my program **not** to run more than 4 threads simultaneously.
My problem is that I cannot execute other threads after the first 4 have been spawned (and completed).
Why do I get this weird behvaiour?
The function `func` is a simple `g_print` because I'm only testing how GThreadPool works.

```
gpointer func(gpointer data, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print("hey\n");
    g_thread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: What does "cannot execute other threads after the first 4 have been spawned " mean ? What did you do, what happened ?

Comment: It means that after 4 threads have been correctly executed and terminated, no more threads can be created. They are placed in the queue and they're never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this weird behavior because you call `g_thread_exit(NULL);` in the callback handler of the thread pool. Remove that call.

The thread pool is not designed to handle the fact that your code exits a thread that is managed by the thread pool.

Comment: interested! Just for curiosity, may I ask you where do you have read it? Because in the official GThreadPool docs I haven't found anything. However, thanks a lot nos :)

Comment: It isn't explicitly documented, but most thread pools are not made with the idea that the user should interact directly with the threads, and the source code of GThreadPool doesn't have any means to handle one of it threads exiting.